# Code for polyfill requestNextAnimationFrame code

Tags: javascript

I have the following code from Core HTML 5 canvas:

```
    window.requestNextAnimationFrame = (function() {
    var originalWebkitRequestAnimationFrame = undefined,
    wrapper = undefined,
    callback = undefined,
    geckoVersion = 0,
    userAgent = navigator.userAgent,
    index = 0,
    self = this;

    // Workaround for Chrome 10 bug where Chrome
    // does not pass the time to the animation function

    if (window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame) {
        wrapper = function(time) {

            if (time === undefined) {
                time += new Date();
            }

            self.callback(time);
        };

        // Make the switch

        originalWebkitRequestAnimationFrame = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;

        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame = function(wrapper, element) {
            self.callback = callback;

            // Browser calls the wrapper and wrapper calls the callback

            originalWebkitRequestAnimationFrame(wrapper, element);
        };
    }

    // Workaround for Gecko 2.0, which has a bug in
    // mozRequestAnimationFrame() that restricts animations
    // to 30-40 fps.

    if (window.mozRequestAnimationFrame) {
        // Check the Gecko version. Gecko is used by browsers
        // other than Firefox. Gecko 2.0 corresponds to
        // Firefox 4.0.

        index = userAgent.indexOf('rv:');

        if (userAgent.indexOf('Gecko') != -1) {
            geckoVersion = userAgent.substr(index + 3, 3);

            if (geckoVersion === '2.0') {
                // Forces the return statement to fall through
                // to the setTimeout() function.

                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame = undefined;
            }
        }
    }

    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||

         function(callback, element) {
             var start,
                finish;

             window.setTimeout(function() {
                 start = +new Date();
                 callback(start);
                 finish = +new Date();

                 self.timeout = 1000 / 60 - (finish - start);

             }, self.timeout);
         };
})();
```

When I look in Chrome console, it seems to have window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame as well as window.requestAnimationFrame. Correct me if I'm wrong, but window.requestAnimationFrame is the newer one, and it's the one I should be using.

If that's true, then doesn't this code spent time constructing things for window.requestNextAnimationFrame? Shouldn't it skip that code if the version of Chrome I have also has window.requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: There's no `window.requestNextAnimationFrame` in Chrome (v34, at least). There's `window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame`, though.

Comment: @MaxArt Thanks for catching that. It was meant to say window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `window.requestAnimationFrame` is defined, a developer should give for granted what it works as the specs. Everything else should be taken case by case. `webkit.webkitRequestAnimationFrame` should be ignored.

Also, I'd like to add that very old browsers sometimes can live with their broken implementations. In particular, if Firefox 4 is limited to 40 fps, nothing bad will really happen, since we can say that nobody uses Firefox 4 anymore, and if someone does 40 fps is good for most of the cases.

Same thing for Chrome 10 (nobody *should* even use it anymore): the workaround seems overkill to me. If you really want to fix a bug, you may want to check if the bug is there *first*, for example:

```
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(function(time) {
    if (time === undefined) {
        // ... Fix!
    }
});
```

Remember: user agent sniffing is *bad*.

The less the code you serve, the better. This is my opinion, anyway. You should adapt everything to your case (and user base).

Comment: And do you know why chrome has these two functions?

Comment: @GarthMarenghi It wouldn't be the first time that Chrome has both the prefixed and unprefixed version of something. I guest it's for some compatibility reason. I've never noticed any difference in any case.